# Вытащить данные из функции PhoneGap

Tags: phonegap, android, ios, blackberry, javascript

Добрый день всем, я уже задавал похожий вопрос недели две - три назад здесь, но так я проблему решить и не смог. Проблема эта выглядит следующим образом: использую функцию `phonegap - getMetadata()` я вывожу данные из функции. Код выглядит так:

```
entry.getMetadata(lastFileModDate, fail); //lastFileModDate функция которая выводит дату
```

метод `getMetadata` получает название функции "`lastFileModDate`", потом создает объект "`metadata`" и вызывает функцию `lastFileModDate`, передав этот объект
Эта функция имеет вот такой вид:

```
function lastFileModDate(metadata) {
    console.log(metadata.modificationTime);
}
```

Простое присваивание переменной ничего не дает выдает `undefined` поэтому обращаюсь к Вам, люди. Перепробовал много разных методов, ни один не подошел.

Вот так выглядит функция в которой все творится:

```
function listResults(entries) {
    entries.forEach(function (entry) {
        //....
        var a;

        function lastFileModDate(metadata) {
            console.log(metadata.modificationTime);
            a = metadata.modificationTime;
        }
        entry.getMetadata(lastFileModDate, fail); //Отправка функции lastFileModDate
        console.log(a); //undefined
    }
```

Как мне получить данные которые приходят в lastFileModDate(metadata) ?

```
//проверяем готов ли девайс к использованию
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
//та же проверка
function onDeviceReady() {
    window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, onFileSystemSuccess, fail);
}
//массив списка файлов
function toArray(list) {
    return Array.prototype.slice.call(list || [], 0);
}

//смотрим всем папки
function onFileSystemSuccess(fileSystem) {
    var dirReader = fileSystem.root.createReader();
    var entries = [];
    var readEntries = function () {
        dirReader.readEntries(function (results) {
            if (results.length) {
                entries = entries.concat(toArray(results));
                listResults(entries);
            }
        }, fail);
    };
    readEntries();
}

//какую папку открывать
function onFileSystemSuccess(fileSystem) {
    fileSystem.root.getDirectory(fileListDir, { //адрес к папке
        create: true,
        exclusive: false
    }, getDirSuccess, fail);
}

//если папка существует то открываем и входим в неё
function getDirSuccess(dirEntry) {
    var directoryReader = dirEntry.createReader();
    directoryReader.readEntries(listResults, fail);
}

var gStr = '';
//посылаем список файлов и папок и сами файлы
function listResults(entries) {
    entries.forEach(function (entry) {

        if (entry.isDirectory) {
            gStr += 'dir_' + dir_i + '=' + entry.name + " ";
            dir_i++;
        } else {
            //последняя дата редактирования файла
            function lastFileModDate(metadata) {
                //console.log(metadata.modificationTime);
                modTime = metadata.modificationTime;
            }

            //размер файла
            function fileSize(file) {
                //console.log(file.size);
                fSize = file.size;
            }
            entry.getMetadata(lastFileModDate, fail);
            console.log(modTime);
            entry.file(fileSize, fail);
            gStr += 'file_' + file_i + '=' + entry.name + ' date_file_' + file_i + '=' + +' file_size_' + file_i + '=' + fSize + " | ";
            file_i++;
        }
    });
    //если файл тогда ->
    if (itm.locname.isFile) {
        //КИДАЕМ ФАЙЛЫ
    } else {
        //посылаем нас сервер сами файлы
        /*$.post(task_url + "/" + userfotos, gStr, 
                   function(data) {
                     //alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
                   }
           );*/
        //console.log(gStr);
        console.log(gStr);
    }
}
//если не получилось
function fail(evt) {
    console.log("Error " + evt.target + evt.error + evt.code);
}
//если получилось
function win(r) {
    console.log("success");
    console.log("Sent = " + r.bytesSent);
}
```

Comment: console.log(a); //undefined

А что вы пытаетесь сделать позже с переменной "а"? передать ее значение в другую функцию?

Comment: entry.getMetadata(metadata.modificationTime, fail); //Отправка функции lastFileModDate

Comment: console.log(metadata.modificationTime);  - а тут чтото выводится?

Comment: получается ты массив хочешь присвоить переменной

Comment: или присвоить массиву и брать 1 или И-тый элемент, или сразу без присваивания брать какой надо элемент, или перебирать его и брать нужный элемент...

Comment: @Gorets не вижу проблемы с массивом (или точнее объектом в том случае). Если там и массив, он спокойно присвоится переменной и в console.log(a); должно написать object или что-то наподобие, но никак не undefined. Тут дело в чем-то другом.

Comment: есть еще идеи?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Кроме синтаксических ошибок и не объявленных переменных в приведенном тексте ошибка в том, что [FileEntry](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/cordova_file_file.md.html#FileEntry).[getMetadata()](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/cordova_file_file.md.html#FileEntry_getmetadata) (то же для директорий), а также [FileEntry](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/cordova_file_file.md.html#FileEntry).[file()](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/cordova_file_file.md.html#FileEntry_file) - **асинхронные**, иначе зачем там callback'и. Узнавать размер файла или дату модификации сразу после вызова этих функций бессмысленно. андроид не такой быстрый =)

В общем так просто ошибку исправить не получится. Нужно переписать получение списка файлов и их параметров в асинхронном стиле. Метаданные, кстати говоря, получать не обязательно, и дата и размер есть в самом файле ([File](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/cordova_file_file.md.html#File)).

Comment: А можно поподробней по поводу  "переписать асинхронно", как это? "Метаданные, кстати говоря, получать не обязательно, и дата и размер есть в самом файле (File)." Придется переписывать все? Когда я в своем коде пишу entry.size и entry.lastModifidate мне выдает undefined, как мне переписать нужно что бы выводило нормально?

Comment: @Yura Ivanov, отлично, тебя тут оказывается ждали 2-3 недели и 2 дня.. =) хороший ответ..

Comment: @Gorets, многабукф было, думал и без меня справятся, долго обходил стороной =)  
@dajver, если решать в лоб, то вам надо завести глобальный массив файлов, в цикле по entries вызывать file() и в колбэке заполнять этот глобальный массив со всеми необходимыми данными. Факт окончания заполнения - количество в массиве файлов = количеству в массиве entries. дальше когда все будет заполнено можно будет пробежаться по этому глобальному массиву и получить gStr конкатенацией.
как-то так.

Answer (score 3):

Попробуйте заменить

```
   var a;
   function lastFileModDate(metadata) {
        console.log(metadata.modificationTime);
        a = metadata.modificationTime;
   }
   entry.getMetadata(lastFileModDate, fail); //Отправка функции lastFileModDate
   console.log(a); //undefined
```

на

```
   function lastFileModDate(metadata) {
        console.log(metadata.modificationTime);
        return metadata.modificationTime;
   }
   var a = entry.getMetadata(lastFileModDate, fail); 
   console.log(a); //undefined
```

Смысл таков:

- вызывается entry.getMetadata()
- при успешном получении данных она вызывает lastFileModDate и передает данные
- lastFileModDate из данных получает metadata.modificationTime и возвращает их из функции
- var a = entry.getMetadata(lastFileModDate, fail); получает эти данные.

**UPD**: Странно, что у вас не работает. Вот написал для теста тот же принцип, который вы объяснили и он работает нормально с присваиванием.

```
var a; //объявляем переменную
function getMetadata(callBackFunction) { //наша функция getMetadata
 var metadata = {}; //получаем объект сданными
 metadata.modificationTime = '33'; // допустим вот такое время создания
 callBackFunction(metadata ); // вызываем колбэк и передаем туда данные
}
function lastFileModDate(metadata) {
 a = metadata.modificationTime; //присваеваем значение времени в нашу переменную
}
getMetadata(lastFileModDate); //Вызываем функцию для файла
alert(a); //проверяем значение переменной А​
```

[Пример](http://jsfiddle.net/pHx9r/1/)

Возможно нужно больше кода, что бы найти ошибку.

Проставьте console.log() после каждого действия и смотрите на каком этапе происходит сбой :)

Comment: Вы попробуйте первый вариант, второй не сработает (я уже заглянул в документацию), но первый должен сработать :) Второй вариант сейчас удалю как неактуальный.

Comment: Ну не воссоздавать же мне для теста всю модель? 

entry.getMetadata() - здесь это метод объекта который делает манипуляции определенные.

У меня в примере отдельно стоящая функция которая делает приблизительно то же. 

Сам принцип присвоения должен был бы отработать, но у вас не получается. И в чем причина по данному куску кода сложно определить. Весь код программы мы не видим  :) Один выход - debuging.

Comment: А если вот так попробовать, что в логах будет?

function lastFileModDate(metadata) {

 console.log(metadata.modificationTime);

 modTime = metadata.modificationTime;

 console.log(modTime);

}

console.log(modTime);

Comment: Ок, а fileSize из функции ниже возвращает значение или тоже undefined?

Comment: так же undefined